# Google API Authorization with AWS Lambda - FileDataStore not supported

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, google-api, aws-lambda, google-authentication

I have created a WebAPI and published it to AWS Lambda. Within this API I am automatically sending some emails via GMail SMTP. My email code looks like this:

```
var secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GMailClientId"),
    ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GMailClientSecret")
};

var googleCredentials = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom }, ((MailboxAddress)message.From.First()).Address, CancellationToken.None);
if (googleCredentials.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
{
    await googleCredentials.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(googleCredentials.UserId, googleCredentials.Token.AccessToken);
    client.Authenticate(oauth2);

    await client.SendAsync(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my local machine but when try to run it through AWS Lambda I get the following error when calling `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync`:

> Relative FileDataStore paths not supported on this platform.

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` defines `AuthorizeAsync` as :

```
public static Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets, IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore = null, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver = null);
```

I am not supplying anything to the dataStore parameter so by default it is using the `FileDataStore` implementation.

I'm guessing Lambda doesn't like this because it's trying to access the file system.

Has anyone come across this problem before and if so do you know of a solution? I'm not sure any of the Google implementations for `IDataStore` would work?
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.2/interfaceGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Util_1_1Store_1_1IDataStore

**EDIT:**
I wonder if I need to create a db implementation of IDataStore? Something like: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088092/ADO-NET-Implementation-of-Google-API-IDataStore. Seems a bit odd that Google doesn't supply such an implementation though...

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ? i am having a similar issue